# Why is the size of my .Private folder so large?

Tags: filesystem, encryption, disk-management

Last night I had about 190GB of free space on my 500GB HDD.  Today I have about 80GB free.  I ran `df` and discovered that my `/home/jon/.Private` folder is currently using 80% of my hard drive.

What.  The.  Hell.

I really don't need to encrypt my files that bad.  Can anyone tell me why I've lost so much space to this, and what I can do to recover as much free space as possible?

I realize that I'm not going to get back 330-something odd GB of space, but I lost 100GB overnight.  I'm new enough to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) that I don't want to proceed without a firm understanding of what's going on here.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 7):

Since its contents are encrypted, you are unlikely to be able to tell much by looking at the files in `~/.Private` directly.

Instead, you'd be better off looking at the unencrypted view of those same files in `~/Private`.  The `ecryptfs` system has quite a low overhead, so if `~/.Private` is large it is likely because you've placed a lot of data in `~/Private` (or a program running on your behalf has done so).

Comment: I'm currently not using that environment since I noticed that my free space was steadily diminishing so I can't check directly, but I could swear that I don't actually have a ~/Private directory.  Is that even possible or am I just missing the obvious?

Comment: Yep, I'm back in Ubuntu and there is no ~/Private.  What does that mean?

Comment: Is it possible that you deleted the `~/Private` directory at some point?  That wouldn't have cleared the encrypted files found within.  Assuming the key also hasn't been removed, you could try running `mkdir ~/Private` followed by `ecryptfs-mount-private` in a terminal might be enough to regain access.

Comment: You might also find https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory useful in understanding how the system works.

Comment: `ecryptfs-mount-private` did not restore anything to ~/Private after I created the directory.  Using `sudo ecryptfs-mount-private` prompted me for my passphrase.  Thankfully (and totally by accident) I remember my passphrase, but after entering it I get an error: `fopen: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through a similar situation on Ubuntu 16.04. Not having ever set up the `~/Private` folder, but with the `~/.Private` folder taking up 90% of disk space available. In my case I had enabled the `/home` folder encryption option during install; it seems that in such case the `~/.Private` folder is set up automatically for the purpose. You can verify it, if the `~/.Private` folder is a link to `/home/.encryptfs` this is most likely the case:

```
$ ll ~/.Private
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 33 nov  1 16:25 /home/user/.Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/
```

I do not know exactly what causes this expansion of the encrypted file system, but it is basically the `~/.Trash` folder. I just needed to empty the Trash in the DE to bring things back to normal. I suspect that when single files are removed from the Trash they somehow remain in the encrypted file system; emptying the Trash fixes this.

Note that it may take several minutes for the system to report the correct space usage after the Trash is emptied.

Comment: I second this. Emptying the trash clear me 1.5 GB+ of data that is impossible to clear otherwise

Comment: What is the DE?