# Problem with hard drive space

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, home-directory, disk-usage

I have a problem, my .private is using the 100% of my free hard drive space, i have no idea of how to solve this...

Why is file is using every bit on my hd, how can i fix it?

This is the menssage of space using on the terminal:

```
andrey@andrey-vaio:~$ df -k
S.ficheros            1K-bloques     Usado Disponible Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda3               53876204   7128424   44010988  14% /
udev                     1848456         4    1848452   1% /dev
tmpfs                     757452       920     756532   1% /run
none                        5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none                     1893624       396    1893228   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1              249920700 236820380     405008 100% /home
/home/andrey/.Private  249920700 236820380     405008 100% /home/andrey
/dev/sr0                 4482226   4482226          0 100% /media/disk
```

I have my home on a particion and the OS on other, the big problem is that now a couldn't save documents because i don't have free space.

Comment: Similar question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/97954/why-is-the-size-of-my-private-folder-so-large

Comment: Yeah but this post doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Does the ~/Private directory exist? All content of any files or folders you write in ~/Private will be encrypted when written to the disk, in the hidden directory ~/.Private.

Comment: yeah, i've noticed that .private is growing and growing all the time, today i only have 300MD of free space on my HD when my home is just using 20GB, it means this .private is eating my HD.

Comment: how can i reset .private and the encryption config of /.Private?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider removing the encrypted private directory if so follow the steps below.

To remove this setup:

1. Ensure that you have moved all relevant data out of your ~/Private directory
2. Unmount your encrypted private directory

   ```
   $ ecryptfs-umount-private
   ```
3. Make ~/Private writable again

   ```
   $ chmod 700 ~/Private
   ```
4. Remove ~/Private, ~/.Private, ~/.ecryptfs (Note: THIS IS VERY PERMANENT AND WILL DELETE ALL YOUR FILES, NOT JUST THE ENCRYPTED COPIES!)

   ```
    $ rm -rf ~/Private ~/.Private ~/.ecryptfs
   ```
5. Uninstall the utilities

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0
   ```

**Resources:**

[Encrypted Private Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory)

Comment: thanks! i'll try it tomorrow because i have to make a backup of my files before.