# Decrypting ~/.Private/ folder

Tags: encryption

Okay, so I just realised that my `~/.Private/` folder is huge (22GB) and that my `~/Private` folder is empty. I tried decrypting the folder with `sudo ecryptfs-mount-private`, I entered my passphrase correctly and got the following error:

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [removed] into the user session keyring
fopen: No such file or directory
keyctl_search: Success
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'
```

`ecryptfs-mount-private` without `sudo` simply returns without echoing anything. Any idea what might be wrong?

I really don't need this home encryption if it's gonna take up so much space.

So, my questions are:

1. How do I decrypt/unencrypt the contents of `~/.Private/`?
2. How do I stop stuff from being encrypted? As far as I've understood it everything in `~/Private/` gets encrypted, but I haven't moved anything to that folder and it didn't exist before I created it.

My problems are very similar to this question: [Why is the size of my .Private folder so large?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97954/why-is-the-size-of-my-private-folder-so-large)

Comment: Have you consulted [the manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory), in especially the section "recovering your data automatically"?

Comment: I'm currently running sudo ecryptfs-recover-private from my terminal. Will post another comment when it's done.

Comment: Alright, it succesfully mounted my private data @ some read-only location in /tmp/, I checked out the folders and it seems to simply be a copy of my /home/ directory, gonna take a backup of it in case there are some interesting differences between the two.

Now I am rather worried: 

As my /home/ folder doesn't reside in ~/Private/ how will I properly remove it? It seems to me that the 'usual method' would not work. Perhaps I should simply make a backup of ~, remove the .Private stuff and just copy paste it into my folder again?